# Remove comma at the begining at the of new results output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script to copy values from span class values in a form. When I copy more than one the script adds a comma at the beginning of the returned results. Not sure what the problem is.

```
<script>
var results = [];

$('input[name="clickme"]').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('class');
    $('table#' + id).toggleClass('selected');

    var PROC_CODE = $('table#' + id + ' .PROC_CODE').text();
    var MEDICARE = $('table#' + id + ' .MEDICARE').text();
    var STATUS = $('table#' + id + ' .STATUS').text();
    var ATA_ID = $('table#' + id + ' .ATA_ID').text();
    var SYS_APP = $('table#' + id + ' .SYS_APP').text();
    var SUBMITTER = $('table#' + id + ' .SUBMITTER').text();
    var EMAIL = $('table#' + id + ' .EMAIL').text();
    var ADD_CPT = $('table#' + id + ' .ADD_CPT').text();
    var change = $('table#' + id + ' .change').text();

    if ($('input.' + id).is(':checked')) {
        results.push(PROC_CODE + '\n' + SYS_APP + '\n' + change + '\n\n');
        if ('console' in window) console.log(results);
        $('#results').val(results);
    } else {
        results.pop(PROC_CODE + '\n' + SYS_APP + '\n' + change + '\n\n');
        $('#results').val(results);
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the HTML that this script is running over?

Comment: And a sample of the bogus produced `results`.

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net with an example of it breaking?

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = [];
```

You have declared result as an array.

```
results.push(PROC_CODE + '\n' + SYS_APP + '\n' + change + '\n\n');
```

you are pushing elements into array

```
$('#results').val(results);
```

results array will be converted into comma seperated string and then it will be put into your #results  element

**To solve do something like below i.e.**

```
var result=''; //using as string
```

...
change

```
 results.push(PROC_CODE + '\n' + SYS_APP + '\n' + change + '\n\n');
```

to

```
results= results + ' '+ PROC_CODE + '\n' + SYS_APP + '\n' + change + '\n\n';
```